# Shrink the data file on Azure SQL MI

Tags: shrink, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have a 600GB DB with 400GB free space in the data file on Azure SQL MI.
I am planning to shrink it and save the storage, but it's a critical DB with the user sessions.

There are two plans:

Plan A: Shrink the data file down to 210GB at one time.

Plan B: Shrink 5GB every time and execute one by one.

Do you have any thoughts? What's the benefit of plan B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly the only difference I can think of is Plan A will cause continuous database contention, where Plan B will be shorter periods of contention at a time, but could take longer to complete overall. If you have a very *busy* database, Plan B *may* minimize performance issues, but if your database is set to grow in increments greater than the rate you can shrink by 5 GB, then it may be a fruitless attempt.

Additionally, you shouldn't normally be shrinking your database as it's generally a wasteful heavier operation. Instead you should determine what caused the large growth, if it was normal, and if your database growth settings are appropriately configured.

Comment: As an additional point, doing the shrink in a loop will allow you to "complete" some shrinking, so if something were to happen, you don't have to start all over. With an all-in-one shrink, if the query fails, gets killed, etc. you will have to shrink from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, J.D. Since it is a busy database and I will try PLAN B. much appreciated your suggestions.